# Extension of the Sylvester-Gallai theorem?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry

The **Sylvester-Gallai** theorem asserts that given a finite number of points in the euclidean plane, either:

1. the points are collinear
2. there exists an ordinary line (i.e. a line that contains *exactly* two of the given points).

> **Question:**
>   Is it possible to extend this result to more general (complete) 2-manifolds (where "lines" are replaced by geodesics)?
>   And if so, what conditions must these 2-manifolds satisfy?

I'm quite surprised that I haven't found anything about this question on the internet.
It seems to be a quite natural question.

References are also much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

I have a feeling that the correct generalization consist in studying the effect of the failure's of Euclid's fifth postulate on the *two* on condition due.

So you should probably study the number of points where two geodesics "in general position" intersects on your 2-manifold, and then change the *two* according to that. For example, on $S^2$ two geodesics intersect in two different points, and in fact the theorem as stated is false, for example pick the set of points $\{ (0,0, \pm 1),(0, \pm 1, 0), (\pm 1, 0,0) \}$ with the usual embedding of $S^2$ in $\mathbb R^3$. It is clear that every geodesic passing for two of these points meets two more points of the set, even though the 6 points are not collinear.

Comment: So you really want your theorem to work with *two* points. Then I have no clue which condition you could impose on the curvature, perhaps non-negativeness? The theorem seems to work for hyperbolic plane by the way.

Comment: My first guess would be: non-positive curvature. I too think that the theorem works for hyperbolic space, did you find a proof or a reference by any chance?

Comment: No, I just thought at the Poincare's disk model. I think the theorem is equivalent to say two geodesics intersect in at most one point, and this happens in the hyperbolic space.

Comment: Dave, in the Klein model of hyperbolic space, geodesics are chords of the Euclidean sphere, so the Euclidean Sylvester-Gallai theorem implies the hyperbolic one.

Comment: Another example: in the model of a flat torus where opposite sides of a square are identified, it is possible to embed the affine plane over any field of prime order p: just draw a square grid of side length 1/p. In these finite planes, any line passes through p points.